# Gerrit api to change or delete the access levels for a project

Tags: rest, gerrit

Is there any gerrit REST API or any other way through which we can change the access levels through a script... i did notice that gerrit has the API's to retrive and update other details..but have not found any wrt access levels..

Pls advice.

Comment: Reading docs first would be a good idea ;-)

Comment: I did go through the documentation for the latest version of gerrit ..i could find the cmd line options to fetch the projects list and other details..but could not find any option to change the access list for a specific branch for a project.

Comment: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8.2/cmd-index.html.. this is the link which i have been though.

Comment: See my answer below. You find REST API (for read access only) docs [here](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8.2/rest-api-access.html) and for read/write access through Git [here](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8.2/config-project-config.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Git to manage the project config through the [refs/meta/config](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-project-config.html) refspec.

There are [REST APIs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-access.html) atm. only for reading access settings.

Comment: The current REST endpoints described by the documentation you link to don't allow _changing_ the ACLs of a project, only listing the current ACL.